# Bitcoin exchange fees

Tags: fees, cryptocurrency

Where would you go to sell a large quantity of Bitcoin?  The major exchanges (such as Coinbase, Gemini, etc.) charge exchange fees in the neighborhood of 1.5% of the amount being exchanged.  Are there good lower priced alternatives?

Comment: A word of caution - crypto trading services are largely unregulated and unmonitored; be careful who you trust [what, you didn't really think BTC was "trustless", did you?].

Comment: Coinbase Pro has more reasonable fees for large transactions.

Comment: @rocky:  That's very useful.  Thank you.  It looks like there is no membership fee for coinbase pro so I'm a little mystified why people ever use coinbase instead of coinbase pro.

Comment: 1.5% is pretty low to buy and sell currencies !

Comment: @Fattie I just checked and my stock broker appears to charge $10 + 0.2%, which crosses over at about $769. (for general currency exchange, not for Bitcoin)

Comment: Welcome new user, thanks for the superb and on-point question.